# Why are some files being removed from the solution but not deleted?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I right-click some files of my project (in this case an ASP.NET Core web application), there's an entry named **Delete** which deletes the selected file and removes it from my solution.

On other files (as in the screenshot below), there isn't **Delete**, but there is **Remove** instead of it. The difference is that the files are removed from the solution, but not deleted from the hard disk.

So far I couldn't figure out when **Delete** is shown as option and when **Remove** is shown. Does anybody have further information about it?

[image: Visual Studio Remove vs Delete]

Comment: In my VS 2017, it is always "Delete", even on .cshtml files... projects have "remove" though...